# traversal tree with Lens and Zippers

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

I'm learning the Lens package. I must say it's a rather challenging task.

Can someone show me how to traverse a Tree with Zipper from Lens? In particular, how can I write a function that takes a list of roots and allows me to access the branches of the sub-tree?

Suppose I have this tree. If my input is `[1, 3]`, the function should allow me access node 10 and 11.

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Tree
import Data.Tree.Lens

testTree = Node 1 [ Node 2 [ Node 4 [ Node 6 [], Node 8 [] ],
                             Node 5 [ Node 7 [], Node 9 [] ] ],
                    Node 3 [ Node 10 [], 
                             Node 11 [] ] 
                  ]

zipperTree = zipper testTree
```

In addition, how exactly do I use `saveTape` and `restoreTape` to save the traversal path (to a StateT or IORef)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

edit: I normally experiment in ghci to understand new code so for those like myself I have created a [School of Haskell post/page](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/davorak/zipper-tree-examples) which comes with the below examples but they are editable and runnable.

---

Think this examples will answer your questions but for expediency I am going to modify a different node.  My knowledge of the zipper functions in the 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) is rather shallow. It takes a little longer to read and get used to the types in the 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package compared to many other packages, but afterwards it is not bad. I had not used the zipper module or the tree module in the lens package before this post.

The trees do not pretty pretty well with `show` so if I have time I will come back and add some pretty printed out put otherwise it is probably key to work in the repl with these examples to see what is happening.

## Viewing

If I want to view the value of the first node, according to the [tree lens package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.8.7.3/doc/html/Data-Tree-Lens.html) this is referred to as the root, then you can:

```
zipperTree & downward root & view focus
```

## Modifying

To modify that value and recreate the tree(rezip the tree):

```
zipperTree & downward root & focus .~ 10 & rezip
```

If you wanted to move down the branches then you need to use `downward branches`.  Here is an example that modifies the root of the first branch and rezipx the tree:

```
zipperTree & downward branches 
           & fromWithin traverse 
           & downward root 
           & focus .~ 5 
           & rezip
```

Here I move downward to the list of branchs.  I then use `fromWithin` use use `traverse` to traverse the list, if this was a tuple I could use `both` instead.

## Saving and replaying traversal paths

`saveTape` and `restoreTape` allow for you to save your position in the zipper so that it can be restored latter.

Save a position:

```
tape = zipperTree & downward branches 
                  & fromWithin traverse 
                  & downward root 
                  & saveTape
```

Then to recreate the traversal through the tree I can:

```
t <- (restoreTape tape testTree)
```

Then you can use t as the new zipper and modify it as normal:

```
t & focus .~ 15 & rezip
```

The tape replays the steps that you took so can work on other trees so the follow would work with the tape as defined above:

```
testTree2 = Node 1 [ Node 2 [] ]
t2 <- (restoreTape tape testTree2)
t2 & focus .~ 25 & rezip
```

## Modifying Multiple locations

If you want to modify multiple roots just hold off on reziping the zipper. The following modifies the two roots of testTree2:

```
zipper testTree2 & downward root 
                 & focus .~ 11 
                 & upward 
                 & downward branches 
                 & fromWithin traverse 
                 & downward root 
                 & focus .~ 111 
                 & rezip
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, it doesn't quite address my homework (just kidding). I'm not trying to modify a particular node. Instead, I wish to traverse the whole tree, and record the path to a certain node that satisfies some condition. In your "modifying" example, you know the path is `zipperTree & within (root.traverse.branches) >>= saveTape`. I was wondering how I can get the path without knowing it before hand (by traversing it).

Comment: A concrete example with more details would be helpful then. With the primitives above and recursion it is possible to visit every node in the tree,look at each value and apply a test to it.  After the test succeeds you would just return the tape or save it in a state or writer monad if that is better for your application.

Comment: This is very helpful! How do I use Data.Tree.Lens on my own tree types? Specifically, what if its a binary tree instead of a rose tree?

Comment: @nont root and branches are just lenses defined for the rose tree. So I would use the `makeLenses`, a TH helper, to produces lenses for my custom data structure weather a tree or otherwise.  Then use `downward`, `focus`, `upward`, `fromWithin`, and `rezip` as normal.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, you typically don't want a **Zipper**. In this case you can define a **Traversal** which will allows you to access subforests given a path of root nodes.

```
-- Make things a little easier to read
leaf :: a -> Tree a
leaf = return

testForest :: Forest Int
testForest = [ Node 1 [ Node 2 [ Node 4 [ leaf 6, leaf 8]
                               , Node 5 [ leaf 7, leaf 9]]
                      , Node 3 [ leaf 10, leaf 11]]]

-- | Handy version of foldr with arguments flipped
foldEndo :: (a -> b -> b) -> [a] -> b -> b
foldEndo f xs z = foldr f z xs

-- | Traverse the subforests under a given path specified by the values of
-- the parent nodes.
path :: Eq a => [a] -> Traversal' (Forest a) (Forest a)
path = foldEndo $ \k ->     -- for each key in the list
       traverse               -- traverse each tree in the forest
     . filtered (hasRoot k)   -- traverse a tree when the root matches
     . branches               -- traverse the subforest of the tree

  where
  hasRoot :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
  hasRoot k t = k == view root t

-- | Helper function for looking at 'Forest's.
look :: Show a => Forest a -> IO ()
look = putStr . drawForest . (fmap . fmap) show

-- Just show 'path' in action

demo1 = look $ testForest & path [1,3] .~ []
demo2 = look $ testForest & path [1,3] . traverse . root *~ 2
demo3 = look $ testForest ^. path [1,3]
demo4 = [] == testForest ^. path [9,3]
demo5 = traverseOf_ (path [1,3]) print testForest
```